# Dataflow jobs fail after a few 410 errors (while writing to GCS)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I found a similar SO question from August which is more or less what my team is experiencing with our dataflow pipelines recently. 
[How to recover from Cloud Dataflow job failed on com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165693/how-to-recover-from-cloud-dataflow-job-failed-on-com-google-api-client-googleapi)

Here is the exception (a few 410 exceptions were thrown over a span of ~1 hour, but I am pasting only the last one)

```
(9f012f4bc185d790): java.io.IOException: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:431)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:289)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.TextSink$TextFileWriter.close(TextSink.java:243)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:97)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:80)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:287)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:223)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:193)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:173)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:160)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.throwIfNotOpen(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:408)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:286)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.TextSink$TextFileWriter.close(TextSink.java:243)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.abort(WriteOperation.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:86)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
    ... 4 more
 2016-12-18 (18:58:58) Workflow failed. Causes: (8e88b50b0d86156a): S26:up:2016-12-18:userprofile-lifetime-20161218/Write/D...
(d3b59c20088d726e): Workflow failed. Causes: (8e88b50b0d86156a): S26:up:2016-12-18:userprofile-lifetime-20161218/Write/DataflowPipelineRunner.BatchWrite/Finalize failed., (2f2e396b6ba3aaa2): A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on: userprofile-lifetime-diff-12181745-c04d-harness-0xq5, userprofile-lifetime-diff-12181745-c04d-harness-adga, userprofile-lifetime-diff-12181745-c04d-harness-cz30, userprofile-lifetime-diff-12181745-c04d-harness-lt9m
```

Here is the job id: 2016-12-18_17_45_23-2873252511714037422

I am re-running the same job with the number of shards specified (to be 4000 as this job runs daily and normally outputs ~4k files), based on the answer to the other SO question I mentioned earlier.
Is there a reason why limiting the number of shards to a number below 10k helps? Knowing this can be useful for us to re-design our pipeline if needed.

Also, when the number of shards is specified, the job is taking much longer than it would without it specified (mainly because of the step that writes to GCS) -- in terms of $'s, this job usually costs $75-80 (and we run this job daily), whereas it cost $130-$140 (that is a 74% increase) when I specified the number of shards (other steps seem to have run for the same duration, more or less -- the job id is 2016-12-18_19_30_32-7274262445792076535). So we really want to avoid having to specify the number of shards, if possible.

Any help and suggestions will be really appreciated!

-- Follow-up
The output of this job seems to be disappearing and then appearing in GCS when I try 'gsutil ls' at the output directory, even 10+ hours after the job is completed. This may be a related issue, but I created a separate question here (["gsutil ls" shows a different list every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227291/gsutil-ls-shows-a-different-list-every-time)).

Answer (score 3):

Yes -- specifying the number of shards enforces additional constraints on how Dataflow executes the job and may impact performance. For example,[dynamic work rebalancing](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/05/no-shard-left-behind-dynamic-work-rebalancing-in-google-cloud-dataflow) is incompatible with a fixed number of shards.

As far as I understand, the `410 gone` is a temporary GCS issue, and generally Dataflow's retry mechanism can work around it. However, if it occurs at too high a rate, it has the potential to fail the job. In batch mode, Dataflow will fail the job if a single bundle fails 4 times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. On our end, is there anything we can do when this (410 gone) happens? We usually re-run the job and most of the time it would run just fine, but recently we are seeing much higher error rate and failures of dataflow jobs. According to GCP outage page, GCS seems to be running just fine, so we are wondering why this is affecting our pipelines. Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Looking a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

The 410 Gone errors that happened in this job seem to be harmless (they've been successfully retried).

The job was taking longer, AFAIK, not due to sharding per se but due to workers "losing contact with the service" and that was because of hitting the RPC quota issues, which I think Frances said have since been fixed.

Note, your job will be much cheaper if you don't disable autoscaling, since then Dataflow will be allowed to shut down idle workers.

Please let me know if you're still experiencing performance issues with fixed sharding!