# DataProc Spark Error com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

Having run a spark job on YARN, after about 9 hours the job fails with

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:446)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: 
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 
Gone
{
 "code" : 503,
 "errors" : [ {
 "domain" : "global",
 "message" : "Backend Error",
 "reason" : "backendError"
 } ],
 "message" : "Backend Error"
}
at  com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:432)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:287)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage$WritableByteChannelImpl.close(CacheSupplementedGoogleCloudStorage.java:68)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.close(Channels.java:178)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopOutputStream.close(GoogleHadoopOutputStream.java:126)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:106)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:400)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:117)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:112)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetFileFormat.scala:569)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:422)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$4.apply(WriterContainer.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1348)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:438)
... 8 more
Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.flushRowGroupToStore(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:147)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:113)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetFileFormat.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$5.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1357)
    ... 9 more
```

I have seen solutions here for [Dataflow jobs fail after a few 410 errors (while writing to GCS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41215541/dataflow-jobs-fail-after-a-few-410-errors-while-writing-to-gcs) and [How to recover from Cloud Dataflow job failed on com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 410 Gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165693/how-to-recover-from-cloud-dataflow-job-failed-on-com-google-api-client-googleapi)

but these suggest sharding on DataFlow (not DataProc+YARN). I have also seen https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#410_Gone which suggests a lost re-sumable session which I have no control over.

using

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.bigdataoss</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcs-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Are there any sharding, spark, GCP or YARN partition settings that can help avoid/prevent this exception?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of fixing a smaller number of shards in Dataflow would be to add a step in your Spark job before any output step to `myData.repartition(1000)` or some other fixed number smaller than whatever the partitioning happens to be at that stage. There can indeed be issues when number of partitions is very high (> say 10,000 or so).

Also to set retries, you can add a job property at submission time:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.task.maxFailures=20 ...
```

Or if you want it set at time of cluster creation time:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create --properties spark:spark.task.maxFailures=20 ...
```

Comment: This approach worked for me. Even though I only had about 2,000 partitions, repartitioning by 1,000 before saving seems to have eliminated these errors.